# Does Google Docs have these features?

Tags: google-drive

I have used Google Docs for my documents.
And I just knew [Evernote](http://evernote.com/) which has some awesome features.

Evernote is very nice.
Especially I like the features.

- tagging (and it can be searched later)
- clipping to Evernote
- send data via email (you know, *blablabla.96dcb@m.evernote.com*)

I want to remember everything as soon as I can.
And Evernote is a powerful tool what I wanted.
But I've used Google Docs for long time, and I'm using many other Google services.

Can Google Docs do these?  -or are there official plans?
I don't care if it is **little** inconvenient.

Comment: Evernote is a note-taking app, Google Docs is a productivity suite. It's a different type of app. Google Notebook (http://www.google.com/notebook/), though very simple compared to Evernote, might be what you've been looking for. However, Google has cancelled the product and no longer allows new users to use it and has stopped distributing the clipping extensions.

Comment: @limitedmage: oh bad news. So do you think is Evernote the best app for note-taking apps? Is there no alternative?

Comment: OneNote is my choice. It syncs to SkyDrive and you can use it on your desktop in Office 2010, on the web with Windows Live Office, and on your phone (WP7 or iPhone). It's free except if you want Office 2010 to go with it. There's very powerful tagging and clipping (IE and Firefox extensions). If you use Outlook it will also integrate with your email. You can also collaborate on documents and make it very wiki-like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tagging - this isn't a standard function in Google Docs, I think the closest you can come is setting up folders. searching through the documents is pretty easy (as you'd expect from Google!)

Clipping - Can't be done natively, I think I read about an app someone had produced that would do this, but I never tried it.

Email - I think this used to happen, but I don't think so anymore. However, you can always email to your gmail account and then open the document in Google docs, this would add it to your library.

Comment: *about an app someone had produced* Could you give me the URL?

Comment: The app I mentioned is called NoteSync which is an Adobe Air application which costs $4.99 http://adobe.ly/i8N1V2

Comment: @AlasdairCM, But a file could only be in *one* folder right? That is totally different from tagging, where multiple tags can be applied to a single file...